# Query huge MySQL DB

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL DB with two columns. 'Key' and 'Used'. Key is a string, Used is an integer. Is there a very fast way to search for a specific Key and then return the Use in a huge MySQL DB with 6000000 rows of data.

Comment: Try with creating an `index` on key

Comment: The output from a `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` would be useful, to identify whether a suitable index already exists or not, and depending on what engine is being used, an appropriate indexing strategy. Also, the output from `EXPLAIN SELECT` ... would show us the access plan.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it fast by creating an index on `key` field:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_key_idx ON mytable (`key`);
```

You can actually make it even faster for reading by creating covering index on both `(key, used)` fields:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_key_used_idx ON mytable (`key`, `used`);
```

In this case, when reading, MySQL could retrieve `used` value from the index itself, without reading the table (index-only scan). However, if you have a lot of write activity, covering index may work slower because now it has to update both an index and actual table.

Comment: Another way is to use Partition table :).

Comment: If key was the cluster key of an InnoDB table, the covering index would not be necessary, since the entire table itself is the index.

Comment: @SumitGupta: I don't think partitioning table will be of any advantage here. It will only bring unnecessary complexity without obvious benefits.

Comment: @mvp, I agree just telling various option, with 6M records index is good only.

Answer (score 0):

The normative SQL for that would be:

```
SELECT t.key, t.used FROM mytable t WHERE t.key = 'particularvalue' ;
```

The output from

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT t.key, t.used FROM mytable t WHERE t.key = 'particularvalue' ;
```

Would give details about the access plan, what indexes are being considered, etc.

The output from a

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable ;
```

would give information about the table, the engine being used and the available indexes, as well as the datatypes.

Slow performance on a query like this is usually indicative of a suboptimal access plan, either because suitable indexes are not available, or not being used.  Sometimes, a characterset mismatch between the column datatype and the literal datatype in the predicate can make an index "unusable" by a particular query.